# Image upload in phonegap using Rest webservice in java

Tags: javascript, rest, cordova, jersey, cordova-2.0.0

I am working phonegap + rest webservice. The service given below is working gud with web application test. the image file was uploaded in the local webserver. But same service is not working in phonegap. Included both codes here.

**RestWebService**

```
        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        public Response uploadFile(

                @FormDataParam("image") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                @FormDataParam("image") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
    System.out.println("entered");
    //some logic .. this method is working good using webapplication ... i tested using html page
    }
```

**Phonegap code**

```
function myDetails()
{

     var options = new FileUploadOptions();
     options.fileKey="file";
     options.fileName=imgByte.substr(imgByte.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
     options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

     var ft = new FileTransfer();
     ft.upload(imgByte, IMGURL, win, fail, options);
     alert("finished calling upload");

    }
function win(r) {
    alert("success");
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}
```

New some guidance

```
 Log cat error :
    04-18 18:30:31.621: E/FileTransfer(9459): {"target":"http:\/\/10.1.6.88:8080\/TodaysAdminAds\/resources\/service\/vendor\/vendorregistration","source":"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 Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3 Pn6\/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL\/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3 Pn6\/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDrwOKT8KcenamBuSCeetIQtISR2P4UvY8UnTgD8KADg9aUY5xj8qTp97ilAAXjA goAXv05pDnPGfw7UYpG2qckleOmOKAAZzyPel4BPAHtimjHJUcHnNKQeeAT\/SgBu9yxGwBcZ3dqcThcgqMYycH9KGLbTtUFu27gGhcHnHNAC8 goGeQV5ox8uMDHuKRepAUY65JoAenXp0p2MdqZkD1 uKcM4PQCgBDzSdTz HFID1yCCPWloAX\/JxSd \/0o7HFA5PagBMkfew2e4HSjHOePalHB7Y lB6cAUAN 7IRgYIzzShhjgfpTZAOG7rz\/jR8wJIIx2oAVWycHoehGafuHbFQ YVkwXQK3IGTmhmYPx8yHqehU0ASbz7rj2pc5wQc9iKZgA\/KO\/rSk7TjI nSgBd5Iz2pQx56YqNtjL8wDDcOMZANKQGAODx0PTFAADjPLAtzjrilB2hVLbj2Peg5OQTTMkkFUc47GgBGUy5XcQoyCw4P4VIkeBjczetAfuYyF6HnOPypWZXG3n8M0AGwZBAOR3x2pcKDkLzSZzztP0peOuDmgA3HPTikJVsjkHv2NGQxHzcHpt6Up4BI5PX3oAX3\/nSeucflS49KMHHQUAAPbAH4UYye9HI n0o5oAT2HX35xS9ucGk5z22 nehhkdTu9QKADGfvY\/wNBA6nr dLn2pMDrzQAA5OOD7UEAkHBH8qU4x1NJg5I7GgAJA6sCPek25JfJxjGOSKNuMYX6ECl5x0J\/GgABJ6g9aUcA4BpvJ6Yx tKMqB0460AKD1G0jnvRgH1pGJHGcE9OKUHPIxQAbcc4ANHfjNIASSDnHUEUEeh\/EigBEwM4z PNKMheOcd6MFcnGT6CgqMjCn\/639aAFJPFGeaaB1GOD0OKMAn3\/AJ0AO6cHJoyAOf5UmOTx PejGOR\/KgBf4vagjIpMtjjafQ4pfU7Rnp0oAAOpyT9aQl9uQAT2B4oyOeCPwzR\/nOO1ADgfaj1oAPsaPmGcgfhQAvakI n FL0pucnqRQAc9QCaX86b3wcYpefu\/LntQAo9xil474pBnvS\/gOKAEPHfmjkA8DrxQCM\/d\/HHWk\/AigBeh7Uo lIOexpR FAB26Uh lLSdz60AKOKWkGMe1KMUAHaijH55oxQAd6MfhQDSUAFLTaU0AIKXFA4ooAWikooAWkpaSgA6UUUUAGKDRRQAdM0nQd6XHvSdO1ACchsdj7UvJHTFJzmlPvigA79qTAPv60dOo6ULjqM4oAXFFHTPagflQAfgKB1Pp2o\/OgD0xQAc9sUnTrmjOBS0AGeDxzRR VA69KAEAwT70tFJ FAByDgj8aXvR2xikHJ6UALQPoRSYwKMDrigAxSYx7 9LjtmjB9qAG89MH60UFQ3XqOeKMcc8UARl1U43KvtRT8L\/cB96KAH4HqaTb VAINKeM4FACYwKQZHc0ZyucEex7Ucc0AA78n\/CjPHT9KPwoBI9KABjjH6UZK9ce2KMn0pPzzQAhUs\/P3D\/DjpQB2xn8KUAjOME\/lQPrj2xg0AJs5zk 9KOPUmnYPpxQTgcHH4UAJgjnnHpQOe2PTNJk56c445oDEHBUknrjkUAO598e9LnIwR7dKaT6j8KQcZx07DjigBwBHPWkwc8\/lQWweKZu9zQBJ7f0poLbzwMdjnmomuYl4eVB9WApjX1so4njz9QaV0i1CT2RZwOBxntQO46fhVdLu1YcTx\/niplKSfdYNj0NCaYnGS3Q7GT lMjAUFB0XjFP6Dk80zEgfIACkcimSK5TIQg5PQd\/zpFKogATBPXv vekCg5R1b3BOaUOCcDdnt8vH\/wCqgBeQpPAOOhGeaTaDgkY45Hak8spyZC3qDijaFXOOOo46GgBrmRiPLKY6ZIOfwxTyCCWYsEAwRjNLtxjHB g5pm4cjflkPPp\/n2oAd5p3hQjezEYBP e9KCw 8CfXnpTvofwpAZNxARSB6Nz WKADJzwCPp0o8xsjIAA6ginBucbWH5YoYrjk4 tAB5inrn8qCygc\/oKZHIMbW2sBwGAp U7AfWgBVC4 XgUmV37QRu649qRVXqBg0FegJPqDQA7bnjg\/hR0z1zSAcUoz9PrQADJHoaPypf50ZoAT8B NJ68Uvv3o negBBx90j6gUpHvz6igHtke4pRx1FACdKQjPv8A0pfpmjOaADnsKToeBxS49qCPr HagBOcZJPH60ueDgfQUnXjeOenrRyOTjH9aAEDDA6HHenH6HPrTSxAJVc\/TApQR054oAXtnBo4pPl6de\/0o69OfT0oAFXb06dvahTjKjOfU0ppOCcenvQAufUY tJz32n0xSgCjH1oAb8vXaKCwAO0n8s0pBz0\/Ck5z3 lAACSMq4HQ8ilGRkdfpSdQeD9cUHjJAJxzx1oAUMe4x6UoY9cHH0pgJBzk5IHUU4FiOwP0oAUkYJA59KMgDr FJ859B70vzDqD HSgAHXg4B6cUhznoCPpRu4GQfyozjjGBQAexXijKjJAOB1NJjAGTx346048EGgBA2DgkZ9ulO57kCkP4flSDB 6BQA8ZPcU0nHWjHqOKCAM4B lAC9e1KPc0i\/U0vSgAyKToaM460vrj VACD9P5UtA\/GgdaAD8 KUUUUAIeKTHvS0lAC0UmKWgAooooAKMUUtABSUtFACUYpaSgAxRRRQAdqT14paTOAaAExjkj8aXFHQ0UAA\/pQfWge1H6UAGKM8cCkI7jr6UvPX8xigAB4pM\/hj1oOe3WjaOpx7UAL27UZpB0OOaX dABSHOOAT7Uv4Unvg\/T0oAXt0xR lNzxnGaUYHHJoAWgYopP89KAEYAcnPFLjtR NIRnByRjpQAtHSjpSdzxzQAdz0\/KmkgE5IzQQxIIPGecUuBnIXBPX3oATn 6fyopNrZPzcZ4GOlFADvpxS5HqM0mMHgUpB7UAJjsBTTwTngdqdikOM4zzQAflmlAyOf5UmewPXpxSK\/B4Kn0NADj6dDRwOgo79qTtgnHXnuKAEyC3APoTjOKACvIyfU9qOO3APfFCqFyAe\/ftQA4gntS845\/lTcBsqVyp4P0pk
```

Comment: Are you seeing any error/exception? Please provide details.

Comment: yeah its show failure alert in Fail function "alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);"

Comment: @Manish Its not hitting the service

Comment: What is the URL that you are using to hit the service? localhost is not going to work. You will need to use the IP address.

Comment: Yeah its working fine... i tested in web application i can upload the image file in the server. The webservice is working gud.. so only i attach the some piece of code there. problem is in client side.

Comment: Can you paste the error code? What is the value of IMGURL? When you run the code in the emulator or device, do you get any errors from the device logs?

Comment: @MrBillau i posted error....in logcat and it shows errorcode - 1 in alert

Comment: Maybe you have to add your server to the whitelist in Cordova/Phonegap? If that doesn't work can you please post more of the logs? It should give you more detailed error messages than just that one line.

Comment: @MBillau i found out the issue.. it was only with webkit browser.. same code working gud in Android 4.1 brwoser